# нужно отсортировать массив с заменной следующего элемента на предыдущий 1,2,3,4,5,6 = 2,1,4,3,6,5

Tags: java

Добрый день нужно отсортировать массив с заменной следующего элемента на предыдущий.2143... ломаю голову уже второй час не могу найти информацию буду очень благодарен если вы скажете что не так с моим кодом
P.Sпонимаю что если элементов будет не четное кол-во то будет исключение: выход за пределы массива

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] mass = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    for (int i = 0; i <mass.length; i+=2) {
      int temp = mass[i];
      mass[i] = mass[i+1];
      mass[i+1] = temp;
        System.out.print(mass[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное  дело было в выводе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да в принципе всё нормально.
Чтобы не было выхода за пределы массива цикл нужно делать до `mass.length-1`. Тогда и четное и нечетное количество элементов обработается правильно.

```
for (int i = 0; i <mass.length-1; i+=2) {
```

А чтобы вывелось на печать нормально нужно либо печатать в цикле 2 элемента - `mass[i]` и `mass[i+1]`, либо выводить массив в отдельном цикле после обработки, чтобы не задумываться об отдельном выводе последнего элемента в случае нечетного их количества

```
for (int i = 0; i <mass.length; i+=2) {
    int temp = mass[i];
    mass[i] = mass[i+1];
    mass[i+1] = temp;
}

for(int i : mass)
    System.out.print(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае входной массив надо отсортировать (например, при помощи [`Arrays.sort(int[] arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-).
Также для вывода содержимого небольшого одномерного массива достаточно использовать стандартный метод [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-).

Затем для перестановки элементов в парах можно начать прохождение с индекса 1 (`i - 1 >= 0`):

```java
Arrays.sort(arr);
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    int tmp = arr[i - 1];
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tmp;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Или же можно ограничить на 1 значения индексов в конце массива (чтобы `i + 1 < n`), как показано в предыдущем ответе.  Также можно переставить значения в массиве без использования третьей переменной, например при помощи XOR:

```java
Arrays.sort(arr);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
    arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[i + 1] ^ (arr[i + 1] = arr[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```